# How to remove string starting with another string inside brackets?

Tags: python, regex

I have this kind of string:

```
hello[_ng11][test]hello3[_ngRTf]
```

and I would like to remove string starting with `_ng` inside brackets

Result should be:

```
hello[][test]hello3[]
```

I did try to do something like this:

```
st = "hello[_ng11][test]hello3[_ngRTf]"
modified_string = re.sub(r"/\[\[_ng[^\]]*\]\]/", "[]", st)
print(modified_string)
```

Comment: You are matchesin `[[` and `]]` instead of `[` and `]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the slashes and reduce square brackets to a single occurrence on both sides of the pattern:

```py
modified_string = re.sub(r"\[_ng[^][]*]", "[]", st)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/vfFj3L):

```py
import re
st = "hello[_ng11][test]hello3[_ngRTf]"
modified_string = re.sub(r"\[_ng[^][]*]", "[]", st)
print(modified_string)
# => hello[][test]hello3[]
```

*Details*:

- `\[_ng` - a `[_ng` string (only the `[` char is special here)
- `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `]` and `[` (smart placing, `]` is the first char in the character class and thus does not need escaping)
- `]` - a `]` char (it is not special outside of a character class)